# Calculate the volume of the set $M$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, volume

We have the set $M=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2+y^2-z^2\leq 1, \ 0 \leq z\leq 3\}$. Draw $M$ and calculate the volume of $M$.

$$$$

I have done the following :

\begin{equation*}\int_M\, dV=\int\int\int\, dx\, dy\, dy\end{equation*} Which are the boundaries of the integrals? Do we have to use spherical coordinates?

Or do we set $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ and $z$ remains $z$ with $0\leq z\leq 3$ ?

Comment: Sure, that's a reasonable start. The question now becomes what is the range of $r$?

Comment: We have then $$x^2+y^2-z^2\leq \Rightarrow r^2-z^2\leq 1 \Rightarrow r^2\leq 1+z^2 \Rightarrow -\sqrt{1+z^2}\leq r\leq \sqrt{1+z^2}$$ right? Then we have to use the inequality for $z$, or not? @peek-a-boo

Comment: yes, that's right

Comment: But what about $\theta$ ? Is it $0\leq \theta\leq \theta$ ? @peek-a-boo

Comment: I suggest you sketch what it looks like. For example, if $z=0$, what is the shape? if $z=1$? If $z=2$? That should make things clearer.

Comment: No, $~ -\sqrt{1+z^2}\leq r\leq \sqrt{1+z^2}$ is not correct. $r$ is simply $0 \leq r\leq \sqrt{1+z^2}$

Comment: So area of cross section is $\pi (1+z^2)$ and you integrate over $0 \leq z \leq 3$

Comment: Ah because $r$ is the radius we consider only positive values, that's why we take $0 \leq r\leq \sqrt{1+z^2}$, right? But which interval do we take for $\theta$ ? @MathLover

Comment: With which online program could I draw that set? @MathLover

Comment: you could use http://geogebra.com/3d

Comment: Do we input $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$ and the intersection with $z=0$ till $z=3$ ? Or what dowe have to write as input? @MathLover

Comment: write $x^2+y^2 - z^2 = 1$ and then add another surface which is plane $z = 3$. You can then see the region that you want.

Comment: Ok! Thank you!! :-) @MathLover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the solid is bounded by a hyperboloid of one sheet between z=0 and z=3.

The volume is found by the disc  method as follows

$$ V = \int _0 ^3 \pi (1+z^2) dz = 12\pi $$

Comment: The term $\pi$ is from the boundaries for $\theta$ ?

Comment: The term $\pi$ is from the area of the circular cross-section.

Comment: Ah so do we not use polar coordinates? I got stuck right now.

Comment: No need for polar, just the disc method.

Comment: Could you explain that further to me? I haven't really understood that.

Comment: We are integrating with respect to z and the cross-section at a typical z is a circular disc  with radius $\sqrt {1+z^2}$ thus the area of  $\pi (1+z^2)$

Comment: I see! With which online program could I draw that set?

Comment: Any 3D graphing calculator, Desmos, Mathlab,...

Comment: Ok! Thank you!! :-)